# R regex: end anchors ($) stops working when preceeded by optional character (?)

Tags: r, regex

Why does my regex stops working when the end anchor ($) is preceeded by an optional caracter anchor (?)? For example

```
library(tidyverse
s   <- '[S|s][EG|eg]?'
s2  <- '^[S|s][EG|eg]?$'

[1] TRUE TRUE
c('s','Seg') %>% str_detect(s2) 
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Wrapping the regex with `[ ]` also did not work

```
s3  <- '^[[S|s][EG|eg]?]$'
c('s','Seg') %>% str_detect(s) 
c('s','Seg') %>% str_detect(s3) 
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[[S|s][EG|eg]?]$` matches

- a **single** character in the list:

`[ S | s`

- and **one** optionnal character in the list:

`E G | e g`

- and a closing square bracket `]`

https://regex101.com/r/Pr4IUq/1

Comment: Ok. Got it. I think my mistake was to confuse the role of `( )` and `[ ]`

Comment: @LucasMation: True ;)